# ANTLR: exclude (skip) tokens when building AST tree

Tags: antlr, antlr3

Given the following grammar (in ANTLR v3):

```
test : value0 COMMA_KEYWORD value1 (COMMA_KEYWORD value2)*;
```

How can we exclude (skip) COMMA_KEYWORD from the AST tree built by ANTLR (and without using a write rule)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alternative to using *rewrite rules* is to use *tree construction operators*:

https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687090/Tree+construction

You can use `!` operator to omit a token or subtree from AST:

```
test : value0 COMMA_KEYWORD! value1 (COMMA_KEYWORD! value2)*;
```